# Многопоточность совместно с Spring Boot

Tags: многопоточность, spring-boot, execute

Я запускаю многопоточный парсинг файлов через Executor. При попытке выполениея возникает ошибка при попытке вызвать сервис из многопоточной задачи. По моему мнению ошибка возникает из за того, что сервис запускаеться из многопоточной среды. Так ли это и как это можно пофиксить ?

Задача: Распарсить 10 файлов тремя потоками и записать каждую порцию в базу данных. Ломаеться при попытке вызвать сервис. (В примере упрщено.)

@Component
public class MyExecutor {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

```
//--> Number of parsing processes
private static final int NTHREDS = 3;

public void executor() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);

    // --> Parsing Tasks
    FileList fileList = new FileList();

    int fileSize = fileList.getList().size();

    for (int i = 1; i <= fileSize; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(i);
        executor.execute(worker);
        logger.info("Parsing task " + i + " start");
    }

    /**
     *  This will make the executor accept no new threads
     *  and finish all existing threads in the queue
     *  Wait until all threads are finish
     */
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    logger.info("Finished all threads");

}
```

// class MyRunnable

```
/**
 * MyRunnable will count the sum of the number from 1 to the parameter
 * countUntil and then write the result to the console.
 * MyRunnable is the task which will be performed
 */

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final long countUntil;

    MyRunnable(long countUntil) {
        this.countUntil = countUntil;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader();
        FileList fileList = new FileList();

        logger.info("Link " + countUntil + "= " + fileList.getList().get((int) countUntil - 1));
        try {
            fileReader.mainReader(fileList.getList().get((int) countUntil - 1));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

// Выполняемая задача

```
    public void mainReader(String list) throws InterruptedException {
        HashMap<String, Integer> listT = getList(list);
            System.out.println("SIZE OF LIST" + listT.size());
            wordsService.addItemsList2(10);
    }

    public synchronized HashMap<String, Integer>  getList(String fileName) {

        HashMap<String, Integer> listOfWords = new HashMap<>();
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            stream.forEach(item -> {
                if (listOfWords.containsKey(item)) {
                    int value = listOfWords.get(item).intValue();
                    listOfWords.put(item, value);
                } else {
                    listOfWords.put(item, 1);
                }
            });

//         stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("EX");
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error #3");
        } finally {
        }
        return listOfWords ;
    }
}
```

// Сервис, который запускаеться

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class WordsServiceImpl implements WordsService {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
    public  void addItemsList2 (int i) {
        System.out.println(i+" is OK");
    }
}
```

// Ексепшен, который возникает при попытке вызвать сервис

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.github.oleiva.services.impl.FileReader.mainReader(FileReader.java:63)
    at io.github.oleiva.core.MyRunnable.run(MyRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: А как WordsService подключен в FileReader? Я правильно понимаю, что NPE возникает в строке `wordsService.addItemsList2(10);`?

Comment: @Maksim В следствии проб и ошибок установлнно, что ошибка возникает из за неправильного имплементации бинов. Нужно через  Autowired, а у меня через Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(i); Но остаеться открытым вопрос, как при  Autowired MyRunnable Runnable , передавать параметр I

Comment: Не-не, стоп. У вас Executor в этом случае будет бином, а воркер - не будет. И почему бы не использовать Spring Batch?